# How many votes to close?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

In [this post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/62350), the first "close vote" needed 4 more for it to take effect. Now, though, that close vote needs 24 buddies to get anywhere.

Why? What is it that determines the necessary number of votes?

(Note: I'm just curious. I'm *explicitly not griping* about the fact that I did receive a close vote.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> that close vote needs 24 buddies to get anywhere.

What do you mean by this?  Questions always need 5 (non-moderator) close votes to close.

Are you seeing the "X votes remaining" option - this refers to *your* votes remaining. So you could vote to close up to 24 questions.

Comment: Ah, yes that's what I see. So I could vote to close 24 (presumably _other_) questions? Got it, that makes sense.

Comment: @KlaymenDK yup. That's.. not super clear when you VTC a question, now that you mention it